# SQLAlchemy many-to-many association querying specific child

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, many-to-many, associations

In the case of many-to-many relationships, an association table can be used in the form of [Association Object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) pattern.

I have the following setup of two classes having a M2M relationship through `UserCouncil` association table.

```py
class Users(Base):
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    salt = Column(String, nullable=False)
    
    councils = relationship('UserCouncil', back_populates='user')


class Councils(Base):
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    users = relationship('UserCouncil', back_populates='council')


class UserCouncil(Base):
    user_id = Column(UUIDType, ForeignKey(Users.id, ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    council_id = Column(UUIDType, ForeignKey(Councils.id, ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)

    role = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

    user = relationship('Users', back_populates='councils')
    council = relationship('Councils', back_populates='users')
```

However, in this situation, suppose I want to search for a council with a specific name `cname` for a given user `user1`. I can do the following:

```py
for council in user1.councils:
    if council.name == cname:
        dosomething(council)
```

Or, alternatively, this:

```py
session.query(UserCouncil) \
       .join(Councils)     \
       .filter((UserCouncil.user_id == user1.id) & (Councils.name == cname)) \
       .first()            \
       .council
```

While the second one is more similar to raw SQL queries and performs better, the first one is simpler. Is there any other, more idiomatic way of expressing this query which is better performing while also utilizing the relationship linkages instead of explicitly writing traditional joins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think even the SQL query you bring as an example might need to go to fetch the `UserCouncil.council` relationship again to the `DB` if it is not loaded in the memory already.

I think that given you want to search directly for the `Council` instance given its `.name` and the `User` instance, this is exactly what you should ask for. Below is the query for that with 2 options on how to filter on `user_id` (you might be more familiar with the second option, so please use it):

```
q = (
    select(Councils)
    .filter(Councils.name == councils_name)
    .filter(Councils.users.any(UserCouncil.user_id == user_id))  # v1: this does not require JOIN, but produces the same result as below
    # .join(UserCouncil).filter(UserCouncil.user_id == user_id)    # v2: join, very similar to original SQL
)
council = session.execute(q).scalars().first()
```

As to making it more simple and idiomatic, I can only suggest to wrap it in a method or property on the `User` instance:

```
class Users(...):
    ...
    def get_council_by_name(self, councils_name):
        q = (
            select(Councils)
            .filter(Councils.name == councils_name)
            .join(UserCouncil).filter(with_parent(self, Users.councils))
        )
        return object_session(self).execute(q).scalars().first()
```

so that you can later call it `user.get_council_by_name('xxx')`

---

*Edit-1: added SQL queries*

v1 of the first `q` query above will generate following SQL:

```
SELECT  councils.id,
        councils.name
FROM    councils
WHERE   councils.name = :name_1
  AND  (EXISTS
         (SELECT  1
          FROM    user_councils
          WHERE   councils.id = user_councils.council_id
            AND   user_councils.user_id = :user_id_1
         )
       )
```

while v2 option will generate:

```
SELECT  councils.id,
        councils.name
FROM    councils
JOIN    user_councils ON councils.id = user_councils.council_id
WHERE   councils.name = :name_1
  AND   user_councils.user_id = :user_id_1
```

Comment: When you say v1 "does not require join", how does it operate exactly?

Comment: please see the edit to the answer with SQL to understand. the SQL might be more "complicated" whereas the python query is "simple"... but the execution speed should be basically the same on the DB level.

Comment: Thanks. :) That cleared things out. Didn't know you could make an `exists` query like this.